# Error while converting the value of getTime() to milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime

Can you please help in the below matter:

I am having an error in the display is that when I am converting to milliseconds it will show wrong values. Iam using getTime() in Java.

My code is:

```
Time absent = rs.getTime("abs_hours");
long absent_cumm= (absent.getTime() );

out.println(absent); // This will display 00:04:00 which is correct
```

But when I am printing absent_cumm

```
out.println(absent_cumm);// This will display -10560000 which is wrong
```

How to convert the absent value into milliseconds?

Comment: Let me clarify: you want to display the time as milliseconds from start of day (00:00:00.000)?

Comment: I want to display the result as milliseconds which is 240000 for the 4 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's at least one way that could work:

```
Time time = Time.valueOf("00:04:00"); // replace with rs.getTime()
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(time);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int ms = (hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second) * 1000;
System.out.println("ms: " + ms);
```

Should correctly print "ms: 240000"

Comment: it is showing an error ---Time time1 = Time.valueOf(rs.getTime("abs_hours")); valueOf(java.lang.String) in java.sql.Time cannot be applied to (java.sql.Time)

Comment: `Time.valueOf()` expects a `String`. `rs.getTime()` returns `Time` object already.